# c# PicturePanel address resolution issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I recently encountered a strange error in c#. I am working on an assignement where i have a multiple picture panel. One of them is used to get the picture while others to show matching.

Here is my code

```
pic.image = image.fromfile("images\\a.png");
```

Okay my problem is this code works until i dont get a picture from a panel directly

For Getting a picture i am using this code

```
if (openPicture.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //----------- Load Picture ----------------------------------
            pictureBox13.Image = Image.FromFile(openPicture.FileName);
        }
```

If i obtain a photo successfully , the first code gives me this error

```
                   "file not found error"
```

Any one got such issue because i cant hardcode the exact location of the image in first code.

Comment: The whole code works if i dont execute the openpicture.showDialog() code to obtain picture.

Comment: Is it really needed to get the picture from the panel. Cant you use the resource here as well?

Comment: :) I can , but now i solved the problem.

Comment: request to post the answer please :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not that smart, but still i found this solution most applicable in my situation

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

I just added this line with each picture to change from relative to absolute.